# Python - Count of all Non zero column for each date and month PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe, and I want the count of all non zero values for interaction per month, date and email

```
    DATE    LOC      EMAIL         INTERATION
    1/11    INDIA    qw@mail.com     0
    1/11    INDIA    ap@mail.com     11
    1/11    LONDON   az@mail.com     2
    2/11    INDIA    qw@mail.com     5
    2/11    INDIA    rw@mail.com     5
    2/11    LONDON   az@mail.com     0
    3/11    LONDON   az@mail.com     1
```

So my resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
    DATE    LOC        INTERATION
    1/11    INDIA         1
    1/11    LONDON        1
    2/11    INDIA         2
    2/11    LONDON        0
    3/11    LONDON        1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try by yourself? I see no question here, just an order. Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`numpy.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['DATE','LOC'], as_index=False)['INTERATION'].agg(np.count_nonzero)
print (df1)
   DATE     LOC  INTERATION
0  1/11   INDIA           1
1  1/11  LONDON           1
2  2/11   INDIA           2
3  2/11  LONDON           0
4  3/11  LONDON           1
```

Another solution is create boolean mask by compre by not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), cast to integers and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(INTERATION = df['INTERATION'].ne(0).astype(int))
       .groupby(['DATE','LOC'], as_index=False)['INTERATION']
       .sum())
```

If need group by column `EMAIL` too:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['DATE','LOC','EMAIL'], as_index=False)['INTERATION'].agg(np.count_nonzero)
print (df2)
   DATE     LOC        EMAIL  INTERATION
0  1/11   INDIA  ap@mail.com           1
1  1/11   INDIA  qw@mail.com           0
2  1/11  LONDON  az@mail.com           1
3  2/11   INDIA  qw@mail.com           1
4  2/11   INDIA  rw@mail.com           1
5  2/11  LONDON  az@mail.com           0
6  3/11  LONDON  az@mail.com           1
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution was very easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

One not necessarily efficient solution is to convert to `bool` and then `sum`. This use the fact `0` / `1` are equivalent to `False` / `True` respectively in calculations:

```
res = df.groupby(['DATE', 'LOC'])['INTERATION']\
        .apply(lambda x: x.astype(bool).sum()).reset_index()

print(res)

   DATE     LOC  INTERATION
0  1/11   INDIA           1
1  1/11  LONDON           1
2  2/11   INDIA           2
3  2/11  LONDON           0
4  3/11  LONDON           1
```